# Unexpected EOF from the server on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am running the following SQL query using the `Navicat` client for Mac:

```
SELECT 
    CREATE_TIME, EMAIL, NUMBER, SNID 
FROM 
    LOG_DEVICE 
WHERE 
    CID = 'T-MOB' 
    AND NUMBER LIKE '12345678%'
```

But when I do, I get `Unexpected EOF from the server`. I have tried adjusting the query to this:

```
SELECT 
    CREATE_TIME, EMAIL, NUMBER, SNID 
FROM 
    LOG_DEVICE 
WHERE 
    CID = 'T-MOB'
```

and it will run without issue. I'm guessing that it has something to do with the `NUMBER` column. I know the column has `NULL` and empty values, but it seems that the error happens at the end of the file.

What is causing this, and how can I handle it? Is there a way to handle the error so that I can complete the query?

UPDATE:

I am running SQL 2005. Not sure that makes a difference, but I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: What is the datatype of the NUMBER column?   You should convert it to a varchar if it is some kind of numeric type.

Comment: @TabAlleman it's `nvarchar`

Comment: what is LOG_DEVICE, a table?  Trying to understand what you mean by "file".

Answer (score 0):

In true Microsoft fashion, this issue was solved by running the exact same query from a PC, using HeidiSQL as the client.

Comment: Navicat is a Microsoft product?